# Is spacetime volume preserved in presence of a mass in General Theory of Relativity (GTR)?

Tags: general-relativity, mass, conservation-laws, mass-energy

In many publications about the warping of spacetime in presence of a mass the metric of spacetime is stretched, expanded :

http://discovermagazine.com/~/media/Images/Issues/2015/april/relativity.jpg
http://discovermagazine.com/2015/april/12-putting-relativity-to-the-test

By the simultaneously introduced additional dimension the overall (hyper)volume of spacetime is also expanded.

So is this common illustration in consonance with theory of general relativity or in other words **is spacetime volume preserved in presence of a mass ?**
If not, how is GTR balanced, meaning how is the change in spacetime volume countered to achieve a closed theory, an universal equilibrium.
It is a bit strange to assume that whenever a new star is born the (hyper-) volume of spacetime increases a bit and in addition this leads to symmetry problems and induces a massive philosophical problem...

Comment: This is a difficult question to answer because the volume of all of spacetime (at least for the simplest solutions) is infinite. Also, when a star is born, the mass was already there previously.

Comment: not all mass was generated at big bang ( big bounce ) there is still energy-mass conversion in both directions https://www.forbes.com/sites/paulrodgers/2014/05/19/einstein-was-right-you-can-turn-energy-into-matter/#7fd858e326ac

Comment: Indeed, but it's energy that warps spacetime, not mass. And anyway I'm not sure why it would be such a big problem for volume to change.

Comment: There is no conservation of spacetime volume, and physicists do not regard this fact as a philosophical problem.

Comment: So is spacetime volume preserved in presence of a mass-energy locally or not ? ( aside from the symmetry and philosophical problems )

Comment: Well, the determinant of the Schwarzschild metric is independent of the mass, so I suppose you could say that local spacetime volume is preserved in that situation. (The radial dimension grows and the time dimension shrinks by the same factor.) I haven’t checked whether this is true for a Kerr black hole. In a Friedman universe, spacetime volume is definitely not preserved.

Comment: black holes are singularities, i mean in case of a conventional star or planet. i think the trace is critical for volume preservation i.e. the trace of the Cauchy stress tensor is the pressure ( compression / expansion of i.e. a fluid )  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_stress_tensor

Comment: The spacetime volume element is the product of the four coordinate differentials with the square root of the metric determinant, if I recall correctly.

Comment: The Schwarzschild metric describes the *exterior* of a non-rotating star or planet.

Comment: It seems odd that your question is posed using trampoline-style illustrations of GR from a popular magazine, but you are now conversing about traces of Cauchy stress tensors. Maybe you should reformulate your question to be more technical.

Comment: In https://ned.ipac.caltech.edu/level5/March01/Carroll3/Carroll2.html your statement about spacetime volume is verified ( Equation 2.44 ). I did not want to copy and post a graphic because of copyright ...

Comment: @ralf htp volume element is not n-form, it is actually tensorial density, the equation 2.44 is volume element only if the determinant of metric is 1.

Comment: Look at (2.48) and the following sentences to see that what I said is true.

Comment: PSE is telling me our discussion is too long. Move it to chat if you want.

Comment: yes you are right with your statements, i found something about Kerr metric : In the Kerr–Schild form of the Kerr metric, the determinant of the metric tensor is everywhere equal to negative one, even near the source. (wikipedia)

Answer (score 4):

The question is not posed in a meaningful way, so GR doesn't answer it. Conservation laws are not statements that a certain quantity is the same if you change the conditions in a certain way. More specifically, in the context of GR, we can't compare spacetime A (without the added mass) and spacetime B (with the added mass) and define whether the same parcel of space has the same volume. There is no way to even decide what constitutes the "same" parcel of space in A and B.

Comment: yes there is cf https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant#Jacobian_determinant

Comment: in addition volume preservation is critical for conservation laws in general via Liouville's theorem ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(Hamiltonian) )

Comment: @ralfhtp Those links refer to conservation of the 3-volume of a certain region as it evolves in time. They're not comparing 4-volumes of *different spacetimes*.

Comment: can be expanded to 4D the underlying concept does not loose its validity. can answer tomorrow, is late here ...

Answer (score -1):

i did research this deeper and think i can answer this now. Thanks to all of you for the help, this is a more complex topic than i initially thought. In some sense Ben Crowell is right with his answer, however this answer is simply not satifying and in addition there is a clean mathematical way how two volumes in $\mathbb{R^n}$ can be compared : the Jacobian determinant ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant#Jacobian_determinant ).

His answer is accurate in the sense that GR does not give an answer to the problem because *GR simply is not a closed theory* and conservation laws simply do not hold anymore in GR cf i.e. https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01691807 and https://motls.blogspot.com/2010/08/why-and-how-energy-is-not-conserved-in.html .

And actually this is a philosophical problem and also a physical that is tried to recover with approaches like the Wheeler-DeWitt equation ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheeler%E2%80%93DeWitt_equation ) that introduces a global Hamiltonian and fixes the global energy to zero what is accurate from a philosophical viewpoint.

If the local spacetime volume in presence of a energy-mass is preserved depends on the used metric, like G. Smith accurately stated in the comments under the question. In the 'cosmological standard model' the Friedman universe, it is not preserved. The Friedmann universe is modeled on a perfect fluid in that only pure expansive stresses are allowed, not even shear stresses so in presence of any energy-mass spacetime volume is definitely not preserved.

i came up with the problem of preservation of spacetime volume because there is a **self-field problem** in electrodynamics ( including QED ) and theories of relativity ( including SR ) cf https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abraham%E2%80%93Lorentz_force